# How to perform a css absolute position in Visual Composer without row/columns?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

How can I insert a simple div that has "position:absolute" relative to the root of the page, made with VC (Visual Composer)?

If I simple add a div with position:absolute, it will be automatically contained in a row and column by VC, even if added through the classical editor and updating the page.

The problem is that the parent row/column has position:relative set on it, such that it's not absolute positioned relative to the page root, but relative to the parent row/column.

How should I solve this? I see 2 options:

1) Set a style on the row to override the position:relative to the default position. It might be a risk if the grid might depend on it.

2) Set a row and column that contains the complete page, and insert my div that has position absolute to the parent row/column that is the first div in the page, such it will be almost like it's relative to the root page.

Let me know how to solve this please ?
- Ed

Comment: position fixed is to the page if thats what you mean by page root

Comment: No fixed is no option as I want it to scroll